# How to parse a message into the DynamicMessage class and then do the iteration through the fields?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Here's what I am trying to figure out, their docs don't explain this well enough, at least to me..

**Senario:**

I have 5 proto files that I generate with protoc for C++. My application needs to receive a message and then be able to iterate through all the fields while accessing their values and names.

What I would like to do is parse a message into the DynamicMessage class and then do the iteration through the fields. This way I don't have to know exactly what message it is and I can handle them all in a single generic way.

I know it's possible to handle the messages by parsing them to their specific type then treating them as their Message base class but for my application that is not desirable.

It looks like what I want to do should be possible via the "--descriptor_set_out" and dynamic message class.

**What I've Tried (*And Failed With*):**

I moved the descriptor.proto into the folder with my protos and included it along side my others in the compilation step. I also set the--descriptor_set_out flag to print to a file "my_descriptors.pb.ds"

I have no idea where to proceed from there.

[Here's what i've referenced, although there isn't much...](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#self-description)
Sorry for the long post, and somewhat vague topic naming schema.

Also, incase it wasn't clear, I assume the messages aren't "Unknown." I assume there will still be the requirement of including the respective headers for each proto so my code knows about the 'unknown' message its handling.

Comment: One question - why do you want to do this? if you're transferring the message description (names and types - which is required to be able to iterate through names of the fields) along with the message itself, you're basically cancelling out the performance and size bonuses of non-self-descripting message (which protobuf is). You could just use JSON for it.

Comment: @DarkWander, my usage was that I have a binary message for efficiency purposes that flows through some pub sub processes. I have another process that I wanted to sit and listen in to all messages flowing through the pub sub process. It could include all the needed headers to decode messages and then I want to output them in a readable KeyValue string into a log file for audit/debugging purposes. I wouldnt want to write a decoder/translator for every new message type I add. Would like to just dump the bytes to the correct type and iterate fields generically.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: my answer is not completely correct I am having some compilation errors regarding conflicts, i will edit when I fix it :). but this is a starting point

It might have been a long time since this question was posted, but I faced something similar this days now working with Protocol Buffers.

First of all the reference is wrong the option on the command that must be added is:

`--descriptor_set_out=<Directory>`

where `Directory` is where your compiled version of the [descriptor.proto](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/68c8762b981a2bbd2b7df3c5565b32ba014c3e34/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto) (or .proto compiled that describes your file) is located.

after this you will have to add the reference to the Descriptor.proto file in your autodescriving .proto file.

```
message MyMessage
{
    required google.protobuf.FileDescriptorSet proto_files = 1;
    ...
}
```

Comment: The step that's missing here is to marry the DescriptorProto reference to a DynamicMessage.  It is loosely discussed here at https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#self-description with no examples :(

Answer (score -1):

The most common way is to use message composition. Something like:

```
message Foo {...}
message Bar {...}
message GenericMessage {
    enum Type {FOO = 1, BAR = 2};
    optional Foo foo = 1;
    optional Bar bar = 2;
}
```

If you make sure that exactly one of either `Foo` or `Bar` is present in each `GenericMessage`, you get the desired behaviour. You read one `GenericMessage` and then process it as one of several specific messages.

Think about refactoring the protocol. If all you need to do is iterate over the fields, maybe you'd be better off with something like a simple key-value map:

```
message ValueMessage {
    required string key = 1;
    optional int IntValue = 2;
    optional string StringValue = 3;
    optional bool BoolValue = 4;
    ...
}
message GenericMessage{
    repeated ValueMessage = 1;
}
```

Or maybe you can refactor you protocol some other way.